# Laravel manual authentication not working for customer model

Tags: laravel

***I trying to manually authenticate a customer,no error messages but i cant set a customer as a authenticated user***

```
$user = Customer::where('customerid', $user->getId())->first();

        Auth::login($user);
```

Comment: can you do `dd(Auth::user()->id)` after you code and what's result?

Comment: Please can you add the code you have in your `config/auth.php` file and also show how you're adding the auth middleware to your routes.

Comment: A quick check. Does the Customer model has Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable contract?

Comment: dd(Auth::user()->id) I added this and run,id is appearing but after go next page or refresh,no authenticated users there

Comment: How do you check if a customer is authenticated? Please could you add one more line of code `dd(Auth::user());` right after the `Auth::login($user)` to see if the user is logged in? If you have changed your config/auth.php, you have to add `guard`

Comment: `<?php $user = Auth::user(); 

echo $user->email;
?>` I check here authenticated user

Comment: `  'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],

        'customer' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'customers',
        ],

        'customer-api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'customers',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],`  I already set the guard

Comment: any body help me to solve the problem

Comment: Hi Pradeep, Can you confirm your Customer model has Authenticatable contract. Also, put a try catch around the login function and let me know if you are getting any exceptions.

Comment: Hi Santhosh, I did but no exceptions